# Lebesgue’s property. Bounded sets.

Tags: general-topology

I am looking for the proof of the following theorem

> **Theorem**
>
> Let $A \subset \mathbb R^n$ bounded. For each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a family of balls $B_1, B_2,\dots, B_m$ with radius less than $\epsilon$, centered in points of $A$ and covering $A$, i.e. $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^m B_k$.

Comment: Can you prove it for a compact set? Look at ways of covering bounded set by compact set

Comment: First hint: You only have to prove it for $A$ a closed ball.

Comment: I guess "bowls" should be "balls".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there a book?

Comment: Take $B$ to be the set of all open balls with centers at points of $A$ and radius $\epsilon/2$. The union of these sets contains the closure $\overline{A}$ of $A$. This is because if $x\overline{A}$, then there is $y\in A$ such that $d(x,y)<\epsilon/2$. Then $x$ is in the ball with center $y$ and radius $\epsilon/2$. Since $\overline{A}$ is compact, then there is $B_1,B_2,...,B_n$, for some finite $n$ that also covers $\overline{A}$ and therefore covers $A$ too.